# Is it possible to search for a panel / button in the properties editor?

Tags: interface

I'm using Blender 2.83 LTS, and I know about pressing F3 to bring up the search dialog, but that only seems to list operators and some subset of what you can find in the pull-down menus (File, Edit, Render, Window, Help).

Is there a way to search the properties editor - for example, I remember from a tutorial I've seen in the past that I can set the world units and scale, but I can't find it except by hunt-and-peck through all the tabs and panels.

Is there a way to search for, e.g. "Unit Scale" and so quickly discover it is in Property Editor -> Scene -> Units -> Unit Scale?

Seems like an add-on which would be great for newbies like me.

(This is similar to [Searching for text in the properties panel](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/127423/20696), except that I'm aiming lower: just finding non-editable UI elements by searching)